# unable to launch appium inspector with iOS11 and Xcode-9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appium

I am getting below error in appium inspector when I try to open appium inspector:

> [sessionCapabilities()] Error response status: 6, Selenium error:
>   Session does not exist

Please note that my automation code is running successfully. I am trying to launch inspector while the script is running.I am using the same session id which is automatically generated in inspector while script is running.

I am using appium 1.2.3 desktop with server 1.7.1,Xcode-9,iOS-11,IPhone 7 Plus real device.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

try this out .. hopefully it may solve your problem
   https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/308

Comment: Thanks for responding.Unfortunately the above link was not helpful.I am facing issue even though I  using APPIUM 1.7.1